# Why is .net core 1.0 apparently much slower than .net framework apps?

Tags: performance, .net-core

I just refactored an existing console app to be compliant with .net core 1.0.

When I compile and run the refactored code on .net 4.5.2 (ie as an exe) it runs in 12 seconds. When I run the same code on .net core 1 (ie using "dotnet") it runs in 24.3 seconds, more than double.

Is this expected behavior? And if not, what are some things I could check for?

Michael

Comment: can you state whether you do `dotnet run myproject` or `dotnet myproject.dll`. The first does a lot of inspect and on-demand compilation and the second just executes a dll. The result differs dramatically.

Comment: I was using "dotnet run.." I was not aware there was another option. Later: I used "dotnet publish" to create a folder of the app and its support libraries and executed that via "dotnet my_app.dll". The timing was only fractionally better. But there is a possible clue: when I did the "publish" it created the publish folder off bin/Debug which makes me think the app might be bloated with debug stuff (?) Can you "publish" without debug stuff and could this be accounting for my slowness?

Comment: I just discovered the "-c release" option for "dotnet publish". It appears that the resultant application is much faster than the one with the debug information in it. In fact, it appears to be about the same speed as the same code running as an executable on the .net framework library.

Comment: @MichaelRayLovett FYI, it's not really about "Debug information", it's about "Debug mode". In that mode, both the C# compiler and the CLR JIT compiler intentionally produce sub-optimal code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usual suspect: did you build (or publish) in Release Mode? Try

```
dotnet publish -c release
```

Note that this will look for the `project.json` file in the current directory.
[More information is provided here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/core/tools/dotnet-publish)

Comment: The documentation for publish didn't make it clear that there were performance implications. But clearly there are...

Comment: I guess they took it for granted as there has always been huge performance difference between DEBUG and RELEASE modes.